# Collapsible menu and amount of links in a web page

Tags: seo, css, javascript

One of my pages contain three levels of a collapsible menu (JS + CSS from mycssmenu.com). There are a dozen first level items displayed to users, each one with various second level items, and finally a lot of third level items, each one containing a related link.

This generates a lot of internal links (300+). 
Because of SEO should I change the way the collapsible menu is displayed to reduce link amount? What do you suggest?  I would like to avoid users to have to open a new page just to only see what are third level items and eventually follow one of its links.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would avoid having so many links in one menu as it makes the menu hard for users to work through. It would be better to stop at the second level and have those links link to a "category" page of links.

If you are sure the menu is usable, the best solution is probably to use Javascript to generate the deeper levels of the menu. You can store the menu structure in JS variables and build it when the page loads.

Comment: _"It would be better to stop at the second level and have those links link to a "category" page of links."_
This is what I am trying to avoid, I want to let users to see at least 4 or 5 third level items for the selected 2nd level item. At this time I am rewriting all the script. "More..." is added (as suggested by other SE user) at the end of 2nd and 3rd levels item selections to see complete category data

Comment: @dstonek do you have an example page so I can see what you have in action?

Comment: Yes. This is the present menu (on the left) [link](http://www.stonek.com/es=JIG) I am working on a new one.

Comment: I don't like what I am doing: trimmed menus with "more" to follow the users to a new page. I am thinking about  display all third level items from a selected second level but to link all of them to the same page adding an anchor to the url to scroll the page until clicked item summary is displayed to the user.  Does google consider repeated urls differing on anchors as  different links? No sure if it is clear: there's a page for each second level item containing a summary of all nested third level items.

Comment: No, anchors do not count. Ranking is given to a page and therefore all links to the same page, different anchors, no anchors or even different URLs for the same canonical, count as the same.