# Collapsible menu and amount of links in a web page

Tags: javascript, css, seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Collapsible menu and amount of links in a web page](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/28684/collapsible-menu-and-amount-of-links-in-a-web-page)

One of my pages contain three levels of a collapsible menu (JS + CSS from mycssmenu.com). There are a dozen first level items displayed to users, each one with various second level items, and finally a lot of third level items, each one containing a link to open related content.

This generates a lot of internal links (300+). Google SEO recommends to have a 'reasonable' number of links in a page. How would I change the menu without affecting the page usability?

I would like to avoid users to have to open a new page just to only look for the wanted third level item he has found from the menu and follow its link.
Hope I was clear, if not I could add a sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consolidate into subpages as you suggested or show only the "top 5" in each category to "everyone" and interrogate a user to get "more info" - process that through AJAX or some sort of marketing capture form ( email addy, etc... )